# Two way binding for template rendered in knockout using jsrender

Tags: knockout.js, jsrender, jsviews

The following link shows default template mode of knockout and two way binding works in it.

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/5wZQ2/136/"
```

But i want to render template using jsrender "render" method. When i'm doing so, data binding works but not two-way binding

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/5wZQ2/137/"
```

Is there any other way to make two way binding work with jsrender "render" method?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jsrender = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var values = valueAccessor();
    var childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(values.data);
    $(element).html($(values.template).render());
    ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childBindingContext, element);
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
  }
}
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wZQ2/140/).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using JsViews - which integrates JsRender and provides full MVVM. See http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvapps.

Here is your example using JsViews:

```
<script type="text/html" id="text">
  {^{if ~root.editable}}
    <input type="text" data-link="name" />
    <input type="checkbox" data-link="verified" />
  {{else}}
    <span data-link="name"></span>
  {{/if}}
</script>

<label><input type="checkbox" data-link="editable" /> Editable</label>

<p>Name: <input data-link="data2.name" /></p>
<p>Verified: <input type="checkbox" data-link="data2.verified" /></p>
//Template
<p>Name2: <span data-link="{for data2 tmpl='#text'}"></span></p>
```

and

```
var viewModel = {
  data2: {name: "Brian", verified: true},
  editable: true,
};

$.link(true, "body", viewModel)
```

Running here: https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/nbyyx08y/